# Как разрешить трафик kubernetes/calico через iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, kubernetes

Я установил на свой хост kubespray. Я хочу закрыть на хосте все порты, кроме нужных. Я хочу добавить такие правила:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Но есть проблема. Последнее правило блокирует трафик kubernetes. Примеры такого трафика:

```
Sep 28 01:37:01 node1 kernel: [1034725.304114] Iptables: Drop close ip: IN=calif886a61144a OUT= MAC=ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:52:e2:a2:07:10:34:08:00 SRC=10.233.102.148 DST=169.254.25.10 LEN=45 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25074 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44106 DPT=53 LEN=25 MARK=0x40000
Sep 28 01:32:22 node1 kernel: [1034445.773838] Iptables: Drop close ip: IN=vxlan.calico OUT= MAC= SRC=10.233.102.128 DST=239.192.152.143 LEN=165 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=32 ID=60561 PROTO=UDP SPT=58704 DPT=6771 LEN=145
Sep 29 00:00:02 host1 kernel: [10232.158702] Ip6tables: Drop other: IN=enp9s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=2a01:04f9:003b:4714:0000:0000:0000:0002 DST=ff15:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:efc0:988f LEN=187 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=32 FLOWLBL=553201 PROTO=UDP SPT=6771 DPT=6771 LEN=147
```

В iptables также имеются правила, созданные kubernetes. Но я это учел и вставляю свои правила после них. Получается, что трафик kubernetes доходит до конца цепочки INPUT.

Какими правилами я могу разрешить весь kubernetes трафик? Как это сделать правильно?